# AdMob SDK vs PlayServices AdMob SDK?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

What SDK should I be using for AdMob?  There are two packages, this is so confusing...
Should I be using the AdMob SDK package or the AdMob that comes with the GooglePlayServices package??  Is there any difference?  Are they the same version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first register your app in ADMOB then download the library they provide after registration it works well, as well as i don't think there is a difference except one SHA-1 signature of both the library are different.

Comment: Well I need both GooglePlayServices and AdMob.  But if there the same then I should be using GooglePlayServices.

Comment: you can refer to GooglePlayServices library project separately ven I did the same thing i'm using both in my 3 projects and both seperately working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use GPS.

It now hold the Admob classes, and in fact contains revamped versions of those classes in the com.google.android.gms.ads package.

Use the new classes from the com.google.android.gms.ads package.

Comment: I need to use leaderboards and achievements as well.  So don't need that.  Good is on crack if they think what they have done makes sense.

Comment: ?? I'm not sure what you think the problem is. The latest GPS contains all the prior play services capabilities like leaderboards, in-app payments etc and it now contains the Admob classes too. So you no longer need to include the Admob library.